# Plotting x-axis and y-axis scales graphael

Tags: charts, graphael, jscharts

I am working on graphael Chart for a Bar Graph as below. I am having difficulty in getting x-axis and y-axis for the below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       window.onload = function () {
                var r = Raphael("holder");
                //r.barchart(x, y, width, height, values(array), opts);
                var barChart =  r.barchart(100, 100, 300, 200, [100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 20], 
                {stacked: true,width: 50,  
                //It is the Space between the bars and the size will be reduced 
                "gutter":"150%",                
                colors: [                   
                    "000-#d00-#900",
                    "000-#f64-#c31",
                    "000-#fc0-#c90",
                    "000-#3a3-#070",
                    "000-#2bc-#089",
                    "000-#00d-#00a",
                    "000-#808-#404"
                ]});
        };
</script>
```

The chart for the above code is as below

[image]

Now I want to have x and y axis values which are empty.X and Y scales.

I have tried few techniques which haven't worked out.I added  **axis: "0 0 1 1"** to the options and tried other few workaround but in vain.

Thanks for replying.